# Xamarin.Mac project crashes on NSApplication.Init

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin.mac

Can you please help me understand why this Xamarin.Mac application is crashing? I am trying to use the GUI library Xwt in Xamarin Studio on a Mac, but even the test project XamMacTest which comes with Xwt crashes. I determined that the crash happens during the call to `NSApplication.Init()`. I noticed that Xwt is not a Xamarin.Mac project, but instead includes a copy of Xamarin.Mac.dll. Is it possible that there is a problem with this dll file? It came with the Xwt download so I would expect it to work. If the problem is with the dll, is there a way I can change the project in Xamarin Studio so that it runs as a Xamarin.Mac project?

Here is an excerpt of what appears to be the relevant information from the crash log:

```
Crashed Thread:        0  tid_403  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000000001000-0000000000004000 [   12K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/Documents/*/MacTest.app/Contents/MacOS/MacTest

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: tid_403  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9f8b449a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x9f997ec3 pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9f814a44 abort + 141
3   libmono-2.0.dylib               0x020cf4a5 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 757
4   libmono-2.0.dylib               0x0211f3a2 mono_arch_handle_altstack_exception + 162 (exceptions-x86.c:1103)
5   libmono-2.0.dylib               0x0200e045 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 501 (mini-runtime.c:2883)
6   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x9f98bebb _sigtramp + 43
7   ???                             0xffffffff 0 + 4294967295
8   libmono-2.0.dylib               0x0200de50 0x2000000 + 56912
9   libxammac.dylib                 0x03bbb46b xamarin_process_managed_exception + 91
10  libxammac.dylib                 0x03bbbdea xamarin_initialize + 1098
11  ???                             0x001f3200 0 + 2044416
12  ???                             0x001f1d61 0 + 2039137
13  ???                             0x001e9c0c 0 + 2006028
14  ???                             0x001e5e3c 0 + 1990204
15  ???                             0x001e5a24 0 + 1989156
16  ???                             0x001e365e 0 + 1979998
17  ???                             0x001e1eec 0 + 1973996
18  ???                             0x001dd80c 0 + 1955852
19  ???                             0x00099fd0 0 + 630736
20  ???                             0x00099c88 0 + 629896
21  ???                             0x0008e398 0 + 582552
22  ???                             0x0008e214 0 + 582164
23  ???                             0x0008d884 0 + 579716
24  ???                             0x0008da8b 0 + 580235
25  libmono-2.0.dylib               0x02011947 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1527 (mini-runtime.c:2547)
26  libmono-2.0.dylib               0x021f55a0 do_runtime_invoke + 96 (object.c:2809)
27  libmono-2.0.dylib               0x021f7ded mono_runtime_exec_main + 1005 (object.c:4585)
28  libmono-2.0.dylib               0x021f791f mono_runtime_run_main + 895 (object.c:4135)
29  libmono-2.0.dylib               0x02093d39 mono_jit_exec + 265 (driver.g.c:1050)
30  libmono-2.0.dylib               0x020963e2 mono_main + 8850 (driver.g.c:2187)
31  com.yourcompany.MacTest         0x0000252f main + 1983
32  com.yourcompany.MacTest         0x00001d65 start + 53
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Xwt may use Xamarin.Mac under the hood.

The crash shows use launching, trying to handle our startup, and appears to be dying throwing a native exception (mono_sigsegv_signal_handler).

Maybe the application log has more information? You might also look to the Xwt group for assistance.